# how to show some info on secondary monitor in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

i have some info that store in DB that should be displays some info about path destination and buses on secondary monitors in passenger terminal waiting rooms
now how can i doing this in c# wpf application?
does it need to design any form and than reflect to monitors or it could be done programmatically? or another way...
i am beginner in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

You can split your application in two executables: The first one to insert data in the database. The second one to display info in secundary monitor, reading the information saved on the database.

The two application can run on same machine or separeted ones. If you can use a dedicated machine you can just run you second app on startup and then send computer output to secundary monitor.
If you need to run then on same machine you should have two videocard on that computer and use them as extended displays. The find a way to send specific app to specific screen. Hope it helps you.